# Want to design scroll bar with values associated with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to design something like this but not clicking, what it is called. Can someone please suggest me some link where I can look for its implementation in Javascript. I am looking for Scroll Bar associated with values to it, but desired result is not coming on Google.

[image: Desired Design]

Comment: [`<input type="range" />`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range)

Comment: Have looked for jQuery UI Slider ? https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

Comment: First result on google for javascript value slider, [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette This is what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There's a D3.js plugin that also uses jQuery UI Slider.  This module lets you display an axis of values along the slider.

http://thematicmapping.org/playground/d3/d3.slider/